# Merging two similar files

Tags: r, merge

I am looking for a way to merge two files with multiple similar identifier columns, but with a different results column. The identifier columns are the same overall, but have a different net result per row between files (i.e. results of an experiment).

Example

```
file1
V1 V2 V3 V4 result
B   B  B  B   15
C   C  C  C   20
A   A  A  A   115

file2
V1 V2 V3 V4 result
A   A  A  A   230
C   C  C  C   2015
F   F  F  F   98
```

I want to merge both files, keeping the V1-V4 columns identical, but then listing the results in two seperate columns in the merged file, possibly with the file identifier:

```
merged
V1 V2 V3 V4 result_file1 result_file2
A   A  A  A     115           230
C   C  C  C     20            2015
F   F  F  F     NA             98
```

I have tried merge(file1, file2, by=all) and by=row.names(), but both do not give the desired output.

Thanks,

A

Comment: `merge(file1, file2, by=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), all=TRUE)` or `all.y=TRUE`.

Comment: Great, works, thanks!